# iOS third party maps

Tags: mapkit, openstreetmap, mapbox

I'm building an iOS app using MapBox for maps and MapQuest for directions data. Are there any limitations as to what an App can use or display in terms of third party (non MapKit) map data? Will an app that displays maps and directions from other sources be approved for the App Store..?

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of the MapBox iOS SDK. Many apps have been approved by Apple with alternative maps and/or directions. Some examples include:

- http://thesilenthistory.com
- http://www.mapofthedead.com
- http://www.bassproshopsgames.com/myguide-Hunt/bass-pro-shops-myguide-hunt
- http://mapcraftapp.com
- http://www.messageme.com
- http://moves-app.com
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/london-tube-tamer-transport/id558106521?mt=8

Additionally, all but the last use MapBox.

Answer (score 1):

Here there are other alternatives that can help you on both sides:

[skobbler iOS SDK](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios)- they offer offline maps, route calculation, turn-by-turn navigation and a free tier plan.

[cartotype](http://www.cartotype.com/) - they offer vector data, maps and routes can be displayed as integrated map layers or overlays.